# DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#, linq

when i use from OrderBy i get this error DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. Parameter name: key. 
i do not know how to  change this code

```
 var resAsc = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate: predicate).OrderBy(s => sortItem.SortItems.Select(w => w.SortText).ToList()).Skip(page * size).Take(page).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

how can i resolve it ?

Edit : I want send parameters to this method for example

```
 string test = "Id";
        SortOption objsort = new SortOption();
        objsort.SortItems = new List<SortItem>();
        objsort.SortItems.Add(new SortItem { SortText = "Id" });
        objsort.SortOrderType = EnumTypes.SortOrder.Ascending;
        var res = ApplicationService.SearchPage(w => w.Id > 2, objsort, 1, 3);
```

and now i get these parameters here

```
  public Paginated<TEntity> SearchPage(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, SortOption sortItem, int page, int size)
    {
        Paginated<TEntity> objPage = new Paginated<TEntity>();
        if (sortItem.SortOrderType == EnumTypes.SortOrder.Ascending)
        {

            var resAsc = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate: predicate).OrderBy(s => sortItem.SortItems.Select(w => w.SortText).ToList()).Skip(page * size).Take(page).ToList().AsQueryable();
            objPage.Data = resAsc;
            objPage.TotalCount = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().Count();
            return objPage;
        }
        var resDesc = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate: predicate).OrderByDescending(s => sortItem.SortItems.Select(w => w.SortText)).Skip(page * size).Take(page).ToList().AsQueryable();
        objPage.Data = resDesc;
        objPage.TotalCount = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().Count();
        return objPage;

    }
```

Actually, i want get this `Id` in the here 
`var resAsc = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate: predicate).OrderBy(s => s.Id).Skip(page * size).Take(page).ToList().AsQueryable();`

Comment: The problem is that you try to order a list of lists. As IEnumerable does not implement `IComparable` this is not possible. By what exactly are you trying to order?

Comment: @NtFreX i edit my question , i want just  to get Id from this `ortItem.SortItems.Select(w => w.SortText)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code or take inspiration from it. It gives you an extension method `IEnumerable<TEntity>` called `Prepare`. This method will select the items which match an predicate then it will order the entities and finnaly paginate it.

You can give as many `ColumnOrderConfiguration` objects as you want. It will use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to create the correct result.

Just keep in mind that you will have to use `Expression<Func<,>>` instead of `Func<,>` and `IDbSet` instead of `IEnumerable` when you work with an database.

```
public class ColumnOrderConfiguration<TEntity>
{
    public Func<TEntity, object> ValueSelector { get; set; } = entity => null;
    public SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; } = SortOrder.Ascending;
}

public static class CollectionPreparationExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> Prepare<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, Func<TEntity, bool> predicate, IEnumerable<ColumnOrderConfiguration<TEntity>> orderConfiguration, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        => entities.Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderConfiguration).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

    private static IEnumerable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, IEnumerable<ColumnOrderConfiguration<TEntity>> orderConfiguration)
    {
        var configurations = orderConfiguration.ToArray();

        if (!configurations.Any())
            return entities;

        var firstOrderConfiguration = configurations.First();
        var orderedEntities = entities.OrderBy(firstOrderConfiguration.ValueSelector, firstOrderConfiguration.SortOrder);

        for (var i = 1; i < configurations.Length; i++)
        {
            orderedEntities = orderedEntities.ThenBy(configurations[i].ValueSelector, configurations[i].SortOrder);
        }
        return orderedEntities;
    }

    private static IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity> ThenBy<TEntity>(this IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity> entities, Func<TEntity, object> valueSelector, SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
            return entities.ThenByDescending(valueSelector);
        return entities.ThenBy(valueSelector);
    }
    private static IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, Func<TEntity, object> valueSelector, SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
            return entities.OrderByDescending(valueSelector);
        return entities.OrderBy(valueSelector);
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it.

```
public class MyTestEntity
{
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
    public string OrderText { get; set; }
    public int ThenOrderBy { get; set; }
}

var entities = new List<MyTestEntity>(new []
{
    new MyTestEntity { IsTrue = true, OrderText = "1234", ThenOrderBy = 4321 },
    new MyTestEntity { IsTrue = true, OrderText = "000001", ThenOrderBy = 000001 },
    new MyTestEntity { IsTrue = false }
});
var searchPredicate = new Func<MyTestEntity, bool>(entity => entity.IsTrue);
var orderConfig = new List<ColumnOrderConfiguration<MyTestEntity>>(new []
{
    // first order by `OrderText` ascending
    new ColumnOrderConfiguration<MyTestEntity>
    {
        ValueSelector = entity => entity.OrderText,
        SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending
    },
    // then order by `ThenOrderBy` descending
    new ColumnOrderConfiguration<MyTestEntity>
    {
        ValueSelector = entity => entity.ThenOrderBy,
        SortOrder = SortOrder.Descending
    }
});
var pageIndex = 0;
var pageSize = 20;

var result = entities.Prepare(searchPredicate, orderConfig, pageIndex, pageSize);
```